# How can I check the chosen preset in Python?

Tags: python

How can I check which preset a user has chosen via Python?

For example, I would like to check whether a user is utilizing the default Interaction preset or the Maya preset.

Is this possible in Python? Or can I only check against specific values (such as `select_mouse`)?

Comment: Related bug report: https://developer.blender.org/T34454

Answer (score 6):

That's not possible in Blender's current preset system implementation.

Plain preset execution operator, [`script.execute_preset`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_8/bpy.ops.script.html#bpy.ops.script.execute_preset), merely executes the script file corresponding to selected preset and changes the menu title temporarily. It doesn't store nor provide access to preset selection info. I needed this feature once, and had to subclass the operator myself to get it.

Yes, you can only check specific values modified by the preset's script file.